# System.DayOfWeek does not contain op_Addition

Tags: powershell, date

I have a method that returns last Saturday's Date, and it used to work on the old place I ran it, but I moved it to a new location to run it and it's not working.  I'm not sure if this version of powerShell is different and that's the issue.  It's saying PSVersion is 4 in the new location. The old location had PSVersion of 5.1.

This is my method, and when I check $newdate, it is empty after this runs and during run.

```
function GetLastSaturdayDate()
{
   $date = Get-Date 
   $newdate = $date.AddDays(-($date.DayOfWeek+1)%7)
   return $newdate
}
```

When I run the commands at the ps commandline, it says the following. I don't see this error message when I'm just running the script:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.DayOfWeek] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $newda = $date.AddDays(-($date.DayOfWeek+1)%7)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any ideas how to get date addition to work in the older powershell version? Maybe I need to include or use something like math?

Comment: `DayOfWeek` is an `enum`.  You need to cast it to `[int]` before trying to do math with it.

Comment: Alternatively, flip the sides and let the type coercion do it for you: `-(1 + $date.DayOfWeek)`

Comment: What is your powershell version ?

Comment: @Fourat It's in the question...

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - thank you so much! That seems to be a good fix (second one...1+). If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `DayOfWeek` member is an enumeration of type `System.DayOfWeek`, [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is trying to use the `System.Enum` type to perform addition, but that type does not support addition unless it has a `Flags` attribute.  The way to remediate this is by flipping your operands so the `DayOfWeek` gets coerced to `System.Int32` instead:

```
1 + $date.DayOfWeek
```

Alternatively (for style), typecast it yourself:

```
[int]$date.DayOfWeek+1
```